# error dimension when manipulating a matrix in python

Tags: python, matlab, syntax

I have a matrix with shape(6,5) defined as :

```
blockmat= [[1,1,1,1,1],[4,4,4,4,4], [2,2,2,2,2], [5,5,5,5,5], [3,3,3,3,3], [6,6,6,6,6]]
```

In matlab, this line of code:

```
for i = 1:2
    blockMat(((n*(i-1))+1): (n*i),((n*(i-1))+1): (n*i)) = eye(n)   #n=3
```

gave me in the first iteration a matrix with shape (6,5) and in the 2nd iteration a (6,6) matrix, however in python, when i wrote :

```
for i in range(1,3):
    blocMat[3*(i-1): 3*i, 3*(i-1): 3*i]= np.eye(3)
```

i got this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-c4459263db11> in <module>
     22 
     23 for i in range(1,3):
---> 24     blocMat[3*(i-1): 3*i, 3*(i-1): 3*i]= np.eye(3)
     25 
     26 

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3,3) into shape (3,2)
```

Comment: What is your expected output? Could you be more explicit?

Answer (score 2):

If you just add `print(blockmat[3*(i-1): 3*i, 3*(i-1): 3*i])` in your `for` loop , You can see that , when `n=1` , you are getting a `3X3` matrix - which you can update to `eye` .

But when `n=2` , you are getting `3X2` matrix - you cannot make `eye` operation on that .

You can see clearly with multiple prints - step-by-step how `blockmat` is updated :

```
import numpy as np

blockmat= np.array([[1,1,1,1,1],[4,4,4,4,4], [2,2,2,2,2], [5,5,5,5,5], [3,3,3,3,3], [6,6,6,6,6]])

print(blockmat)

for i in range(1,3):
    print(blockmat[3*(i-1): 3*i, 3*(i-1): 3*i])
    blockmat[3*(i-1): 3*i, 3*(i-1): 3*i]  = np.eye(3)
    print(blockmat)
```

When `n=2` you get the error.

Answer (score 0):

Since the other answerer has explained what caused this error, I will give you a way to solve it.

pass shape values to `np.eye()`

```
import numpy as np

blockmat= np.array([[1,1,1,1,1],[4,4,4,4,4], [2,2,2,2,2], [5,5,5,5,5], [3,3,3,3,3], [6,6,6,6,6]])

for i in range(1,3):
    x = blockmat[3*(i-1): 3*i, 3*(i-1): 3*i] 
    x = np.eye(x.shape[0],x.shape[1])
    print(x.shape)
```

---

**Output:**

```
(3, 3)
(3, 2)
```